# Scripting languages supported for Git hooks

Tags: git

Which scripting languages does Git hooks support? I see examples of Python, Ruby and Bash. Are these the only ones? I'm mainly interested in using it on windows at the moment and am not proficient in the above. I wanted to know whether it supports anything like VBscript, Powershell or windows batch files? Is there a list of all the supported languages.

Comment: The `#! /bin/sh` that you see in Unix-like-system hooks is how those systems are able to execute shell scripts.  A file whose first two characters are `#!` (and that is executable) is run by reading the rest of the "executable header" (basically, up to the newline; there may be a system-defined limit on size as well) and treating it as the path-name of an interpreter, and then executing the interpreter instead, with the path-name of the "interpret-ee" inserted.  So `#! /bin/sh` makes the OS run `/bin/sh` `script`.  (In other words, it's not a git thing, it's an OS thing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It supports anything that your system knows how to execute.  You can implement your hooks in COBOL if you want!

Comment: Ok I thought there was a limited list because I normally see the example script pre-fixed with things like: #!/bin/sh, I assumed this was so that it knew which language to interpret it as. So do I need to follow a specific convention to write them in, for example, a windows batch script?

Comment: ADD SHA-1 TO TREE GIVING COMMIT.  STORE COMMIT IN REPOSITORY.

Comment: @shreyansp: You don't need to follow any convention other than the one that lets your OS run programs.  If you can invoke your program or script in the terminal, chances are Git can invoke it too.  Pick your favorite language and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There is no comprehensive list of supported languages, but everything that's executable on your box can be used from within git. To illustrate,

```
git config alias.getprop '!powershell -command "& { Get-ItemProperty $1 }"'
git getprop .git/config
```

The above defines a new git command (alias) named 'getprop' and then runs the new command on the .git/config input file, printing out the file properties on win. Overall it should be fine for your local scripts, hooks and aliases. But if you plan to share your git config with others you'll need to use a scripting language that all your peers will have installed in their environment.